Prove that if $\operatorname{lcm}(m,q)=\operatorname{lcm}(n,q)$, then $\operatorname{lcm}(m+n,q)\ge\operatorname{lcm}(n,q)$
Apart from changing $p$ to $q$, this is from an unanswered question that the OP deleted about a week ago. It asks to prove
$$\operatorname{lcm}(m, q)=\operatorname{lcm}(n, q) \;\;\to\;\; \operatorname{lcm}(m + n, q) \ge \operatorname{lcm}(n, q) \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$
Although the original question doesn't specify what the variables are, this question will have them all be positive integers. Using the $p$-adic valuation function, a sufficient condition to prove the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is that, for all primes $p$,
$$\nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(m + n, q)) \ge \nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(n, q)) \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$
Using the prime factorizations, we get for the LHS of \eqref{eq1A} for some non-integer $r$ that
$$\nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(m, q)) = \max(\nu_p(m), \nu_p(q)) = \nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(n, q)) = \max(\nu_p(n), \nu_p(q)) = r \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$
If $\nu_p(q) = r$, then $\nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(m + n, q)) \ge r$. Otherwise, we have $\nu_p(m) = \nu_p(n) = r$, so $p^r \mid m \;\land\; p^r \mid n \;\to\; p^r \mid m + n$. Thus, we once again have $\nu_p(\operatorname{lcm}(m + n, q)) \ge r$. This means \eqref{eq2A} holds in both cases, proving the RHS of \eqref{eq1A} is true.
Are there other methods to prove this?

Basic lcm & gcd properties also quickly prove the inequality by proving $,{\rm lcm}(n,q)\mid {\rm lcm}(m+n,q)$. This yields a "global" proof (vs. your above "local" proof) of this divisibility - see my answer. $\ \ $

Using notation $\begin{align}[x,y] &:= {\rm lcm}(x,y),\\ (x,y)&:= \gcd(x,y)\end{align}\,$ and $\,\color{#c00}{\rm D}:=$ lcm distributes over gcd
$\qquad\underbrace{[q,n]=(\color{#0af}{[q,m]},[q,n])}_{\textstyle \color{#0af}{[q,m]}=[q,n]} \overset{\color{#c00}{\rm D}}= [q,\color{#0a0}{(m,n)}]\ {\large \mid}\ [q,\color{#0a0}{m\!+\!n}]\ $ since $\ \color{#0a0}{(m,n)\mid m\!+\!n}$

if [q,m]=[q,n], doesn't it mean m=n. Why use different symbols?

@don  The bracket notation denotes an $:!\rm lcm,,$ cf. first sentence. $\ \ $

With the LHS of the question's \eqref{eq1A}, using that $\operatorname{lcm}$ is an integral multiple of $q$, and the result of posts such as Prove $\,\gcd(m,n)\operatorname{lcm}(m,n) = mn$, then for some positive integer $k_1$, we can rewrite it to be
$$\frac{mq}{\gcd(m, q)} = \frac{nq}{\gcd(n, q)} = k_{1}q \;\;\to\;\; m = \gcd(m, q)k_1, \; n = \gcd(n, q)k_1 \tag{1}\label{eq1B}$$
Next, we also have
$$m_1 = \gcd(m, q), \; n_1 = \gcd(n, q), \; e = \gcd(m_1, n_1) \;\to\; m_1 = ef, \, n_1 = eg, \, \gcd(f, g) = 1 \tag{2}\label{eq2B}$$
Substituting this into the RHS of \eqref{eq1B} gives
$$m = efk_1, \; n = egk_1 \tag{3}\label{eq3B}$$
From $m_1 \mid q$ and $n_1 \mid q$, we also get
$$ef \mid q \;\to\; q = efk_2, \;\; eg \mid efk_2 \;\to\; g \mid fk_2 \;\to\; g \mid k_2 \;\to\; k_2 = gk_3 \;\to\; q = efgk_3 \tag{4}\label{eq4B}$$
Due to $\gcd\left(\frac{m}{\gcd(m,q)}, \frac{q}{\gcd(m,q)}\right) = 1$, and the similar thing for $n$, along with the RHS of \eqref{eq1B}, \eqref{eq2B} and \eqref{eq4B}, we have
$$\gcd(k_1, gk_3) = 1 \;\land\; \gcd(k_1, fk_3) = 1 \;\to\; \gcd(k_1, fgk_3) = 1 \tag{5}\label{eq5B}$$
Using the above, and the result of posts like Prove that if $\gcd( a, b ) = 1$ then $\gcd( ac, b ) = \gcd( c, b ) $, we get
$$\gcd(m + n, q) = \gcd(e(f + g)k_1, efgk_3) = e\gcd((f + g)k_1, fgk_3) = e\gcd(f + g, fgk_3) \tag{6}\label{eq6B}$$
For positive integers $a$ and $b$, $a \ge \gcd(a, b)$ and $b \ge \gcd(a, b)$, so we finally have
$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
e(f + g) & \ge e\gcd(f + g, fgk_3) \\
(e(f + g)k_{1})q & \ge \gcd(m + n, q)k_{1}q \\
\frac{(m + n)q}{\gcd(m + n, q)} & \ge k_{1}q \\
\operatorname{lcm}(m + n, q) & \ge \operatorname{lcm}(n, q)
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{7}\label{eq7B}$$
